# Create Google Drive channel for PUSH notification using Service Account

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-api, google-drive-api

I'm trying to create a channel in order to receive push notifications when an edit is made on a Google Spreadsheet. The code will be executed on an App Engine Standard Java8 project.

Because a channel can last a maximum of 24 hours, I'm creating a cron that will renew the channel every day.

Here is my configuration:

- I created a service account: `xxxx@yyyy.iam.gserviceaccount.com`
- I verified the domain: `yyyy.appspot.com` (in `Webmaster Tools`)
- I added the domain to cloud console (section `API & Services -> Domain Verification`)
- I created an endpoint which will handle push notification: `https://yyyy.appspot.com/api/drive/push`
- The sheetId is: `foo_bar` (copied by the Spreadsheet browser url itself, like `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/foo_bar/edit`)
- The service account is `Can Edit` on the Sheet

With the Java library `google-api-services-drive:v3-rev102-1.23.0` I created this code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String spreadsheetId = "foo_bar";
    InputStream json = GoogleDriveApi.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("bar.json");

    GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.fromStream(json, new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory());
    if (credential.createScopedRequired()) {
        credential = credential.createScoped(Collections.singleton("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata"));
    }

    Drive service = new Drive.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), credential).build();

    Channel channel = new Channel();
    channel.setAddress("https://example.com/api/drive/push");
    channel.setType("web_hook");
    channel.setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());

    Watch action = service.files().watch(spreadsheetId, channel);
    System.out.println(action.execute().toPrettyString());
}
```

When I execute this code I get this error:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 404 Not Found
{
  "code" : 404,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "location" : "fileId",
    "locationType" : "parameter",
    "message" : "File not found: foo_bar.",
    "reason" : "notFound"
  } ],
  "message" : "File not found: foo_bar."
}
```

From [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/push#making-watch-requests) I quote

> Each notification channel is associated both with a particular user
>   and a particular resource (or set of resources). A watch request will
>   not be successful unless the **current user or service account owns or
>   has permission to access this resource**.

In my case Service Account does not OWNS the resource (Spreadsheet) but indeed has permission on it (`Can Edit` permission, non only `Can View`)

Can a service account be used to create a channel on Google Drive?

Comment: What is the authorization code that you are using? How are you authorizing the service account?

Comment: I updated main question with the full code, including authentication

Answer (score 1):

[`file.watch`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/watch) API requires `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` scope, in the main example I was using only `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata`

Using the following line the example works fine

```
credential = credential.createScoped(Collections.singleton("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"));
```

Comment: Hi @Deviling
Could you please help me in getting this work. I have everything with me but still its not working.
-An endpoint (which I validated & added in Domain verification)
-Receiving success as response of action.execute().toPrettyString())
But could not find why I am not able to recieve notifications.